# Como retornar para a página anterior pelo HandleErrorAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, filtro, filter

Estou tentando implementar um filtro global para tratamento de erros e comecei testando da seguinte forma:

```cs
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var exception = filterContext.Exception;
        var controller = ((Controller)filterContext.Controller);

        if (exception is DbEntityValidationException)
        {
            var dbEx = exception as DbEntityValidationException;
            foreach (var ve in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors))
                controller.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = exception.GetBaseException().Message;
        }

        var routeData = filterContext.RouteData;
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult($"/{currentController}/{currentAction}");
    }
}
```

A princípio quero tratar para que erros de validação do EntityFramwork, que tenham passado pela verificação do `ModelState` nas `Actions` (`if (ModelState.IsValid)`), sejam adicionados no ModelState.

Caso contrário eu quero jogar o erro no `TempData`.

Para ambos eu quero que o usuário seja redirecionado para a página da qual ele efetuou a requisição, mas não estou conseguindo mesmo setando o `Result` do `filterContext`: `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult($"/{currentController}/{currentAction}");`

O filtro está registrado em `FilterCondif.cs` e consigo debugá-lo.

Do TempData eu verifico se há mensagem de erro e então apresento uma mensagem customizada.

Como posso fazer o Redirect para a página anterior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira correta de tratar erros de validação de entidades vindas do contexto é pelo *Controller*:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(MeuModel model)
{
    try
    {
        db.PersonalDetails.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ee)
    {
        foreach (var error in ee.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach(var thisError in error.ValidationErrors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, thisError);
            }                    
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Se você quer que esse comportamento seja comum, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public abstract class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    protected MeuProjetoContext db = new MeuProjetoContext();

    protected virtual boolean PersistirOuFalhar() 
    {
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ee)
        {
            foreach (var error in ee.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach(var thisError in error.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, thisError);
                }                    
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

`MinhaAction` ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(MeuModel model)
{
    db.PersonalDetails.Add(model);
    var resultado = PersistirOuFalhar();

    // Aí você usa resultado da maneira que quiser. 
    // Ou pode simplesmente devolver a View.
    // O ValidationSummary estará preenchido.
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Essa resposta se propunha a seguir um caminho sugerido pelo autor da pergunta, que não é correto para o caso. Erros de validações devem ser tratados diferentemente de erros de aplicação, até porque erros de aplicação não permitem que a *View* anterior seja retornada da mesma forma. Um erro de aplicação precisa exibir detalhes do erro, porque o ASP.NET MVC entende que esses erros não são previstos pelo desenvolvedor.
>
> Para fins didáticos, manterei a resposta aqui porque ela pode ser útil para outros exemplos utilizando `HandleErrorAttribute`.

Eu faria um filtro que registra a URL anterior:

## ~/Attributes/UrlAnteriorAttribute.cs

```
public class UrlAnteriorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
        }
        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.UrlAnterior = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
        }
}
```

Registre globalmente o filtro:

## Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new UrlAnteriorAttribute());
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        ...
    }
}
```

Dentro do `HandleError`:

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var exception = filterContext.Exception;
        var controller = ((Controller)filterContext.Controller);

        if (exception is DbEntityValidationException)
        {
            var dbEx = exception as DbEntityValidationException;
            foreach (var ve in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors))
                controller.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = exception.GetBaseException().Message;
        }

        var routeData = filterContext.RouteData;
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.UrlAnterior);
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que o problema não é tanto com o pegar a url, eu até setei ela manualmente, apesar de ter visto que está funcionando corretamente o seu exemplo (precisei apenas implementar IActionFilter ao invés de IResultFilter - não sei porque). E continuo ainda sendo redirecionado para a página de erro padrão do IIS.

Comment: Existe uma *View* padrão para erros. Posso ainda melhorar a resposta. Se for do seu interesse, complemento.

Comment: Gostaria! Preciso mesmo é voltar para a View anterior.

Comment: Melhor dizendo, quero voltar para a View que fez a requisição. Assim, posso mostrar os erros do modelo no `ValidationSummary` ou a mensagem (alerta) de erro customizada.

Comment: Então, aí eu acho que você está indo pelo caminho errado. `HandleErrorAttribute` não serve pra tratar validação, até porque um erro de validação é diferente de um erro de aplicação. Um erro de aplicação não pode produzir a mesma *View* que um fluxo normal. Ele pede uma *View* só para ele. Se quiser, posso produzir uma segunda resposta com o caminho certo.

Comment: Por favor,  gostaria sim da forma certa! Muito obrigado!